# values without key in json array - php code

Tags: php, arrays, json

In the JSON array, we usually put, key: values.  The code for getting marks of specific student (where code no is posted). The php code:

```
<?php
$results = '{"marks": 
 [
       {"code":"125001", "Maths":"95", "Science":"91", "Biology":"80"},
         ........
   }
 ]
}';


$demo = json_decode($results, true);  
   foreach ( $demo['marks'] as $row ) {  
       if ($row['code'] =='125001') { // do the work
   }
}
?>
```

Can we put only values without mentioning the key names each time - as it will save time. in that case the json array would be:

```
$results = '{"marks": 
[// values for: code, Maths, Science, Biology
{"125001", "95", "91", "80"},
{"125002", "90", "88", "85"}
]}';
```

Please  give some idea in this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want named properties, then use an array (`[]`) instead of an object (`{}`), but then you'll have to access them by index instead of name.

This might save you some time when writing JSON by hand (which you probably shouldn't be doing in the first place: keep your data in a database and generate JSON programatically) but will make it harder to maintain your code (since `2` is less intuitive than `"Science"`).

Comment: In such case, how to modify the code "if ($row['code'] =='125001')"  where the key name code is given?

Comment: See the second half of the first sentence of the answer. See also the last 7 words of the answer which give an example.

Comment: It is better  to mention the code. Moro ever,  I am not generating the JSON code from data base, rather, i putting the entire JSON file

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to embed a JSON text in a PHP program and then process the data with PHP. Just write a PHP array in the first place.